# Accessing Dynamically Built Buttons

Tags: xcode, dynamic, properties, uibutton

I am reusing some code that build UIButtons dynamically (without interface builder).  I am using the addTarget:action:forControlEvents method to perform an action each time a button is pressed.  I change the background color of the button based on the setSelected and isSelected properties.

I have added a reset button in order to deselect all buttons at once.  However, I am having difficulty determining how to access the properties of a dynamically added button.

THe code to create the buttons is as follow:

```
for(int y = 1; y < 10; y++)
{

    for(int x = 1; x < 5; x++){
        z++;

        aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        aButton.frame = CGRectMake(x*x_plot, y_plot, 60, 40);
        [aButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnUnselected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(digitClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [aButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",z] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        aButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
        aButton.tag = z;
        [self.view addSubview:aButton];
    }
    y_plot=y_plot+45; //make a 4x9 grid of buttons
}
```

Comment: you've set the `tag`, so you should just be able to do `UIButton *butt = (UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:tag]`?

Comment: Thanks, Mike!  Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use code like this to go through all your subviews

```
NSArray *ar = self.view.subviews;
[ar enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"I've got 'obj' that is a UIButton on the screen!!!!");
    }
}];
```